# Collections Class in Java

Tags: java, collections

I was going through the `Collections` class in Java and suddenly the question arises: "Do `Collections` methods operate only on `List` in Java, as all the examples are done on lists only?"

I know that `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` can be used to sort the elements. So we don't need `Collection.sort()` for them but what about other methods like `shuffle()`, `reverseOrder()` , `swap()`, etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it *says* it takes a List, it takes a List. Did you read the method signatures?

Comment: Look at the javadoc of [`Collections` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#method.summary), e.g. the very first one, then try answering the question. Down-voting because the *"question does not show any research effort"* (tooltip of down-vote button).

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're asking, but methods like [`swap(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap-java.util.List-int-int-) and [`shuffle(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) do indeed only for work for a `List`. But **no**, methods like [`addAll(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-) work for any `Collection`, like for example `Set` (a subclass).